# Proving the fraction $\frac{n^3 + 2n}{n^4 + 3n^2 + 1}$ is irreducible for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that the fraction $\dfrac{n^3 + 2n}{n^4 + 3n^2 + 1}$ is in lowest terms for every positive integer $n$.

I just don't know how to solve this. I tried polynomial division, expressing the gdc of the two terms as a linear combination, and factorizing the sum of the two terms but nothing really leads anywhere. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't understand why expressing the gcd as a linear combination doesn't lead anywhere. Doesn't it follow from $$(n^2+1)(n^4+3n^2+1)-(n^3+2n)(n^3+2n)=1$$ that the top and bottom of your fraction have no nonconstant common factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(n^3 + 2n \:, n^4 + 3n^2 + 1) = a$ 
$$\color {green} {n^3 + 2n = n( n^2 + 2)} \: \:, \: \color {red} {n^4 + 3n^2 + 1 = n^2(n^2+2) + (n^2 + 1)}$$

$$a \mid (n^2 + 2) \implies a \mid (n^2 + 1) \: \: \:, \text{or} \: \: a \mid n \implies a \mid n^2 \implies a \mid (n^2 + 1)$$

Consecutive integers are coprime $\rightarrow a = 1$.

Comment: This assumes that $a$ divides exactly one of $n$ and $n^2+2$, which would indeed follow if $a$ were prime, but here it may not. Would your solution still work?

Comment: @YousefKaddoura Good point, an easy fix is instead of letting a be the gcd, just let a be a prime that divides both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with linear combinations:
$$
(n^4+3n^2+1)-n(n^3+2n)=n^2+1 \tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
(n^3+2n)-n(n^2+1)=n \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
(n^2+1)-n\cdot n=1 \tag{3}
$$
Just work backwards if you need the linear combination, but this is already sufficient.

\begin{align}
1
&=\color{red}{(n^2+1)}-n\cdot\color{red}{n}
&&\text{by (3)}\\
&=\color{red}{(n^2+1)}-
  n\cdot\bigl(\color{green}{(n^3+2n)}-n\color{red}{(n^2+1)}\bigr) 
&&\text{by (2)} \\
&=(-n)\color{green}{(n^3+2n)}+(n^2+1)\color{red}{(n^2+1)} 
&&\text{reorder}\\
&=(-n)\color{green}{(n^3+2n)}+
  (n^2+1)\bigl(\color{green}{(n^4+3n^2+1)}-n\color{green}{(n^3+2n)}\bigr) 
&&\text{by (1)}\\
&=(n^2+1)\color{green}{(n^4+3n^2+1)}+(-n^3-2n)\color{green}{(n^3+2n)}
&&\text{reorder}
\end{align}

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying. It's based off the Euclidean algorithm, right? However I just can't seem to work backwards to the linear combination. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Gravityman I added the computation; it's not really different from the reverse Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Put  $\,f(x) = x^2\!+3x+1,\ $ and $\ n^k\!-a = n^2\!+2\ $ below

**Lemma** $\ $ Suppose that  $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $f(0)=\pm1 = f(a).\,$ Then $\,f(n^k)\,$
is coprime to $\, n(n^k-a)$.

**Proof** $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ n\!:\,\ n\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, f(n^k)\equiv  f(0)\equiv  \pm1,\, $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$\: \ \ \ {\rm mod}\,\ n^k\!-a\!:\ n^k\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, f(n^k)\equiv f(a)\equiv \pm1\, $ similarly.

Thus $\,f(n^k)\,$ is coprime to $\,n\,$ and $\,n^k\!-a\,$ hence also to their product, [by Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that g.c.d of the fraction equals 1 and to do so use Euclide Algorithm.We have$n^4+3n^2+1=(n^3+2n)n+n^2+1$ thus $g.c.d(n^4+3n^2+1,n^3+2n)$= $g.c.d(n^3+2n,n^2+1)$

$n^3+2n=(n^2+1)n+n$ then $g.c.d(n^3+2n,n^2+1)$= $g.c.d(n^2+1,n)$= $g.c.d(n,1)=1$

Hence the fraction in lowest terms.

Answer (score 0):

using the Euclidean algorithm multiple times.
(n^4+3n^2+1)=n(n^3+2n)+(n^2+1)
(n^3+2n)=n(n^2+1)+n
(n^2+1)=n(n)+1
n=n(1)+0
Thus gcd =1 so the fraction is in lowest term.

Comment: 0

using the Euclidean algorithm multiple times. (n^4+3n^2+1)=n(n^3+2n)+(n^2+1). (n^3+2n)=n(n^2+1)+n. (n^2+1)=n(n)+1. n=n(1)+0 Thus gcd =1 so the fraction is in lowest term.